# Smith transformation

Tags: matrices, smith-normal-form

How to transfer the following matrix into Smith normal form?
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
2   & -2b & 0   \\
0   &  2  & -2c \\
-2a &  0  & 2
\end{matrix}\right]$$
The final answer is
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2|abc-1|
\end{matrix}\right]$$

But how we get it?

Comment: Remember that you might need to use both column and row operations when computing smith normal form, whereas one or the other suffices for Gaussian elimination over a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
2   & -2b & 0   \\
0   &  2  & -2c \\
-2a &  0  & 2
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{r_3\leftarrow r_3+ar_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
 2   & -2b & 0   \\
0   &  2  & -2c \\
0 &   -2ab  & 2
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{c_2\leftarrow c_2+bc_1\;\:}
\begin{bmatrix}
2   & 0 & 0   \\
0   &  2  & -2c \\
0 &   -2ab  & 2
\end{bmatrix} \\[1.5ex]
{}\xrightarrow{r_3\leftarrow r_3+abr_2}
&\begin{bmatrix}
2   & 0 & 0   \\
0   &  2  & -2c \\
0 &   0  & 2-2abc
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{c_3\leftarrow c_3+cc_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
2   & 0 & 0   \\
0   &  2  & 0 \\
0 &   0  & 2(1-abc)
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
Possibly change the sign of the last row.

Comment: last operation isn't a row or column operation instead should it be something like $\frac{c}{1-abc}r_3+r_2 \to r_2$ as long as $abc \neq 1$  and $cc_2+c_3 \to c_3$ if $abc=1$

Comment: But In smith form division is not allowed @N8tron

Comment: okay well I clearly didn't get that. So it should just be $cc_2+c_3 \to c_3$? Just a simply typo?

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted from one step to another, and I didn't fully change  the description of the elementary operation. 'Tis fixed now.